# Parsing JSON in Oracle 11g

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

I need to parse a Json string including structs and arrays of structs. I understand that the question was raised, but two hours of googling did not give a satisfactory result due to the existing restrictions:

- We cannot install large frameworks (except for compiling **ONE**
  separate package). This deprives us of [APEX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html).
- We cannot use temporary tables.

But there are the usual plsql features:

- Any collections
- Data types declared at the package level.
- Actually, within one package, any code that does not contradict the restrictions.

So. As an example of json:

```
vSrc :=
'{
  "NAME": " Arnold  Schwarzenegger",
  "AGE": "35",
  "PARTNER":{
    "NAME":"Sandra Bullock",
    "AGE":"33"
  }
  "CHILDREN": [
    {
      "NAME": "Jhon",
      "AGE": "4"
    },
    {
      "NAME": "Kate",
      "AGE": "8"
    }
  ]
}'
```

We want to be able to receive either a value or an array of json strings by address. For example:

```
v_result := jsonAPI.getJson(source => vSrc, address => 'PARTNER.NAME');
```

Returns the value 'Sandra Bullock', and the call

```
v_result := jsonAPI.getJson(source => vSrc, address => 'CHILDREN');
```

Returns a collection, displaying it with the following code:

```
dbms_output.put_line('First Kid:');
dbms_output.put_line(v_result(1));
dbms_output.put_line('Second Kid:');
dbms_output.put_line(v_result(2));
```

We'll see

```
First Kid:
{"NAME":"Jhon","AGE":"4"}
Second Kid:
{"NAME":"Kate","AGE":"8"}
```

Thus, we can use the elements of this collection as a parameter to call the same api.
Is there a way to parse JSON like this in pure PLSQL? Some well-known open source libraries, for example, or something like that?

Comment: Have you looked at [PL/JSON](https://pljson.github.io/pljson/)? Not sure if that will meet your restrictions, as it's three related packages, plus some types.

Comment: @AlexPoole, I tried to convince the boss to install this library, but was refused. Too many individual packages and data types at the database level. JSON is needed to solve one single problem, and the number of packages after installation in the schema will double. I'm still trying to insist, but I doubt that I will succeed.

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything smaller or simpler, at least without it losing a lot of flexibility. If you're only dealing with one specific kind of JSON doc with a small and well-defined schema I guess you could hard-code the extracts you need with string manipulation, but those are big 'ifs' and likely to cause you more pain later. You could suggest PL/JSON goes in its own schema to isolate it maybe. (Or, of course, upgrade the DB *8-)

Comment: PL/JSON is open source and pretty straightforward.. From looking over it, I don't see any obvious reason you couldn't merge the 3 packages and 4 types into one package. You'd lose the SQL types, but it doesn't sound like you need that. Probably easier than writing your own parser/printer from scratch.

Comment: @kfinity can you tell me which of the ten packages and thirteen types I need to merge? I am having some difficulty with the English language documentation.